# Extending Monitors Causing Screen Issues

Tags: windows-10, amd-graphics-card

After moving houses, I’ve begun to experience an issue with my monitors/graphics card. I can duplicate the displays just fine, but whenever I try to extend my displays (as normal) I experience the screen issues shared in the link below.

I am using a Radeon RX 480 with the most up to date drivers (I installed several days ago and ran for a couple days without issue.) I am using a DVI to HDMI cable for connection.

Here is an image of what I’m seeing: [image]

Comment: That looks like damage. If you hadn't said the screens looked OK duplicated, I'd say the scrambled screen was cracked. So instead, I'll suggest updating your graphics drivers, and then I'd suggest running any sorts of tests available on your GPU hardware to verify it is behaving correctly.

Comment: I can’t update any further so I’ll try uninstalling/reinstalling the driver and get back to you.

Comment: Can you use VGA instead? It may be a cable issue at a higher bit rate from a higher resolution??

Answer (score 0):

Once you have extended the displays verify that the one with the issue is set to a recommended resolution (Or at least compatible; you can try different ones to see which ones work, and render the best)...It happened to me and the default resolution set for my second display after extending was not compatible with it...!

Answer (score 0):

If we have been using it well before moving, according to your description, because you just moved, the issue may be caused by the graphics card not being plugged in or the card is loose (maybe the card slot is slightly loose), it is recommended to try to re-plug the graphics card. We can try 1-3 times to see if we can fix it.

We can try to check if there is a problem with the cable they are connected to.

Since our graphics card driver is up to date, we can try uninstalling or reinstalling the latest graphics card driver.

If the above does not work, it may be a problem with the graphics card itself.